# Style only applied after selecting a row in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Somehow the styles for my DataGrid are only applied after I select a row. This means after I click on a row, all rows and cells completely change how the look.

The following code 'fixes' the problem:

```
   void Window_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridData.UnselectAll();
        DataGridData.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Definition of the DataGrid (The SelectedItem is set in the ViewModel):

```
     <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WASDs}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedWASD}" 
                  x:Name="DataGridData">
```

I have defined multiple styles (Row, Column...) for my DataGrid in a File called DataGrid.xaml. The not loaded Styles are implicit defined:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
```

This file is loaded in the applications app.xaml as the last ResourceDictionary:

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
       <!-- WPF 4.0 workaround      -->
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" />
      <!-- end of workaround -->
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary x:Name="FontSize" Source="..." />
          <ResourceDictionary Source="..." />
          <ResourceDictionary Source="DataGrid.xaml" />
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

What I have tried:

- changing the position of the WPF Workaround
- setting the row Style explicitly

Comment: In [this](http://projekt202.com/blog/2010/xaml-organization/) article author mentioned a bug (search for word `bug`) in `ResourceDictionary` merging. Could be your case.

Comment: Hi @Sinatr, I'm aware of that bug and now have included my full App.xaml in the question.

Comment: Try to put workaround **after** merging.

Comment: try to set RowStyle explicitly

Comment: @pushpraj sadly this is not working, too.